# Prove that if a function can be represented as a power series then this series must be its Maclaurin series.

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

> Prove that if a function can be represented as a power series then
>   this series must be its Maclaurin series.

I have spent several hours thinking about it but I still have no idea how to solve this. Any hints would be most appreciated

EDIT: I have given it some more thought and I guess I have attempted to set up a solution, but I am still not sure of its validity. Could you, please, review this for me?

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$$ 
Lemma: $f$ is differentiable infinitely many times.  
Proof: 
$f'(x) = a_1 + 2a_2x + \dots$ 
Assume that this function is differentiable $n$ times, then
$f^{(n)}(x) = a_n + 2a_{n+1}x+ \dots$ 
Now, $f^{(n+1)}(x) = 2a_{n+1} + 6a_{n+2}x + \dots $

And so I have proven by induction that this function is differentiable infinitely many times.

Now, let's prove that $a_n = \frac{f(0)}{n!}$ by induction. 
1. The base case: for n = 0: 
$$f(0) = a_0 = \frac{f'(0)}{0!}$$
Assume that for an arbitrary $n$ and all natural numbers smaller than $n$ $a_n = \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$. Then, for $n+1$:
$$f^{(n)}(0) = n!a_n + (n+1)!a_{n+1}x$$
$$f^{(n+1)} = (n+1)!a_{n+1}$$
And so this is what was to be shown.

Comment: You need to prove that if $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ then $a_n = f^n(0) / n!$.  You can show this with induction after you prove that you can differentiate $f(x)$ term-by-term.

Comment: Technically, it ought to be "Taylor series" instead of "Maclaurin series". The centre of development need not necessarily be $0$.

Comment: @JairTaylor And how can I prove that this function needs to be differentiable infinitely many times?
EDIT: I think I get it. It's enough to differentiate this series, right?

Comment: I don't see any problem with your proof.